# Weird: logo doesn't show up on Chrome

Tags: image, google-chrome, invisible

For some utterly mysterious reason, the top left logo [on my page](http://goo.gl/jvgdM9) doesn't show up on Chrome (works fine on FF).

Parent theme is "Renovate" with main plugins being Revolution Slider and WPBakery Visual Composer. Not sure if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your css for the page:

```
a[title="The Book Balancer"] img {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-width: none;
}
```

You have some other styles on the page not playing nice with your logo.

Comment: @drake035 I think Chrome is interpretting the `a img { max-width: 100% }` that is in another part of the CSS differently than Firefox, but I don't know enough about the CSS specification to tell you why that is, though.